# Submitting ajax form

Tags: javascript, ajax, liquid

I need to submit this form for it to work. Here is my code, but it doesn't want to work. The request must be sent using this link, for example, https://www.eymedic.form.php. How do I get it to work fine?

```
<form method="POST" id="form" action="#" class="form">     
      <div class="field">
        <label for="input-kitId" class="label is-size-7 has-text-weight-light has-text-left">Order ID</label>
        <div class="field"><div class="control is-expanded">
          <input type="number" id="input-kitId" class="home-form__input input is-danger" name="number" value="" placeholder="Order ID">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="field">
        <label for="input-firstName" class="label is-size-7 has-text-weight-light has-text-left">Email</label>
        <div class="field"><div class="control is-expanded">
          <input type="email" id="input-firstName" class="home-form__input input" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <button type="submit" class="button is-midnightBlue">Generate Booking Reference</button>
    </form>
    
    
  </div>
</div>
    
   
<script>
  
$( "submit" ).click(function() {
      if(form.val()) {
            var msg = $("#form").serialize();
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'https://www.harleymedic.co.uk/qrcodes/form.php',
              data: msg,
              success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.status === 'OK') {window.location.href='second_page.html'}
                else {alert(data.message)};
              }
            });
        };
    });
  
</script>
```

Comment: you aren't cancelling the default submit - also you don't have any `submit` elements.

Comment: $("#form").on("submit", function(){
  e.preventDefault()
  const data = form.serialize()
  const msg = $("#form").serialize();
 $.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.harleymedic.co.uk/qrcodes/form.php',
  method: 'POST',
  dataType: 'html',
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  success: function(data){
          alert('error')
   $('#message').html(data);
  }
 });
});                              ///still not working (((/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have **submit** element, use **form** element instead and submit action should be prevented.

```
$( "form" ).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var msg = $("#form").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://www.harleymedic.co.uk/qrcodes/form.php',
    data: msg,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.status === 'OK') {window.location.href='second_page.html'}
      else {alert(data.message)};
    }
  });
});
```